# Display the first 140 characters from blog post

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I want to get first 140 character from the post content and display it into a homepage. I create plugin for that and it doesn't give me the desire out put. Can you guys tell me where I done mistake and how can I recover it? This is the code that I write in plugin file

```
$length = 140;
function cp_trim_content($length){
$content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $length );

if( count($content) >= $length)
{
array_pop($content);
$content = implode (" ", $content).'...';
} 
else 
{
$content = implode (" ", $content);
}
//$content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
return $content; 
}
```

Comment: You want 140 words or 140 character as your code seems to work for 140 words

Comment: 140 character not a words.. sorry my mistake

Comment: I have posted an answer with minimal code, accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: I use it and paste the php file in to plugin folder. There is not any error in code but yet not get the success. Still get no any single character below my blog post title.

Comment: First of all please check if your function is called and then the next step will be checking if get_the_content() gives you content or not you can refer the below link
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Answer (score 0):

If you want it for 140 character then the below code will work for you

```
    $length = 140;
    function cp_trim_content($length)
    {
        $content = get_the_content();
        if(strlen($content)>$length)
        {
          $final_content = substr($content,0,140).' ...';
        } 
        else
        {
          $final_content = $content;
        }
        return $final_content; 
    }
```